# In Jenkins ,Failed to send out e-mail javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 550 User has no permission

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

Help! In Jenkins ,I found a problem as bellow,Failed to send out e-mail  javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 550 User has no permission

Comment: Please add some context details or email code ?

Comment: the exception code changed,it is 535

Comment: Thank you ,the problem had been solved ,it is because that the password is wrong ,it should be the mailbox's authorization password ,not the mailbox's password.

Comment: @Leo What do you mean by "mailbox's authorization password"?